# FFmpeg: Invalid option 'partitions"?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to speed up video playback by encoding with FFmpeg. I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-vcodec libx264 -vpre ultrafast \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:480,setpts=PTS/1.8[v];[0:a]atempo=1.8[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Running this gives the following error message:

```
~/.ffmpeg/libx264-fast.ffpreset: Invalid option or argument: 'partitions=+parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
', parsed as 'partitions' = '+parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8'
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you running? Show the complete banner.

Comment: Also, how did you obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't knowingly put the profile file (`~/.ffmpeg/libx264-fast.ffpreset`) there, you can just remove it. It may have been valid for a previous version of ffmpeg.

(The `.ffmpeg` folder is a hidden folder in your home directory.)

Instead of `-vpre`, a reasonably recent version of ffmpeg can take the `-preset` option to directly specify a x264 preset. Take a look at the [ffmpeg H.264 guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: I placed it there because ffmpeg complained that `File for preset 'ultrafast' not found`. How do I make use of these profiles with the recent version?

Comment: @ric.row I added an explanation on that to the answer.